# PHP mssql_init('mydb') failing. Stuck trying to call trivial Stored Proc from PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Is there any way to turn on driver logging for PHP/MySQL 5?  Is there a log that shows internally what's going on... like all database activity?  Lower-level errors?

I'm trying to get a trivial PHP page to call a trivial stored proc on Windows 7.  mysql_error isn't returning any error message when the mssql_init() fails.

Thinking it might be a permission problem I created a new user and I get the same results:

```
CREATE USER 'user1'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass1';
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'user1'@'localhost';
```

Here is the code:

```
create table trace (
    trace varchar(50) not null,
    datet datetime not null
);

drop procedure if exists mark;
delimiter !!
create procedure mark()
begin
    insert into trace (trace,datet) values ('mark',now());
end; !!
delimiter ;
```

I can call the SP from MySQL Workbench just fine:

```
call mark();
```

Here is the PHP page:

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user1', 'pass1');
if (!$connection) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$sel = mysql_select_db('tw');
if (!$sel) {
    die('Could not select_db: ' . mysql_error());
}

//$stmt = mssql_init('mark', $connection);
//$stmt = mssql_init('mark', $sel);
$stmt = mssql_init('mark');
if (!$stmt) {
    die('Could not init: ' . mysql_error());
}

$result = mssql_execute($stmt);
if (!$result) {
    die('Could not execute: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_free_result($result);

mssql_free_statement($stmt);

mysql_close($connection);

printf("DONE<br />"); 
?>
```

Other proof of concept pages which demonstrate *insert,* *select,* etc, are working just fine.  Just can't get a stupid stored procedure to run from a web page!

The page output is only this:

> Could not init:

(The [PHP mssql_init documentation page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-init.php) isn't very helpful and seems to have a typo as the $link variable isn't defined.)

Comment: I don't get it... are you using both mysql and mssql O_o?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `mssql_init` (Note ***MS*** SQL) to execute a stored procedure on ***My*** SQL.

Obviously the `mssql_init()` function can't find your Microsoft SQL Server connection 'cause you don't have one. You should only be using `mysql_` functions for a MySQL connection.

And MySQL doesn't have a special function for calling stored procedures. `mysql_query('CALL mark()')` will work just fine.

Comment: OMG DOH!  I need more sleep and/or caffeine.  Sorry to waste your time.  Thanks!